# Integrating multiple query condition

Tags: mysql

I need single query to execute this function in mysql

```
select * from 'users' where user_name like 'account'
```

if no users with name `account` present then i have to use the second query else i can go with the first query.

```
select * from 'users' where user_name like 'manager'
```

is there any way to optimize this into a single query? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
Select IF ((Select count(*) from 'users' where user_name like 'account')>0,
select * from 'users' where user_name like 'account',
select * from 'users' where user_name like 'manager')
```

Comment: Seeing as it is possible there are no user accounts that are like 'account' I doubt the extra count query will add much overhead.  But if efficiency is a huge concern there is probably a cleaner way.

Comment: The cleaner way would be to cave and perform the second query conditionally - depends on the size of the table and indexes

Comment: is there any way to find which account has been used in the search ex(manager or account)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM users m
  LEFT JOIN users a ON a.user_name = 'account'
 WHERE m.user_name = coalesce(a.user_name, 'manager');
```

It will not work properly in case `user_name` is not unique, I thought it should be, actually. It would help to know how table is defined to design the query properly.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea, how about you do

```
select * 
from 'users' 
where user_name like 'account' or  user_name like 'manager' 
order by   user_name
```

than you check the first account, if it is ='account', you delete all the managers from your dataset. If it is manager, there you have your dataset

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use a `IF` statement in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE user_name LIKE 
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE name = 'account'
   ) > 0,'account','manager');
```

Comment: If no record exists where `user_name` is 'account' then the query will try to select a record where `user_name` is 'manager' and that is not the same as doing: `SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = 'account' || `user_name` = 'manager';

Comment: Nope, if it is not account "for a row", it will see if it is manager. Actually OP wants "if no account record at all". But your query will see foreach record, not the entire record. Test it

Comment: in fact this is now the only working solution till now, but I suggest you using `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT(*)` because former is faster. Also it has to be `user_name LIKE 'account'`. you have put an `=` sign there instead of `LIKE`